# How can I create a development server for an app on Google App Engine (Flexible environment)?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, app-engine-flexible, appengine-wordpress

I am trying to set up a development server on a Google Compute Engine VM that is as close as possible to the App Engine Flexible environment deployment of the Wordpress installation built through [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible).

This guides you through on how to:

Get the source
 1. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples.git
 2. /php-docs-samples/wordpress

Install the dependencies
 3. composer install

Setup the App
 4. php wordpress-helper.php setup

Deploy the App
 5. gcloud app deploy

Is it possible to find the Dockerfile equivalent of the App Engine deployment,
or generate an image of the app's instance that can be deployed to a VM instance?

Comment: I have not had a chance to implement it yet but this page talks about getting one setup (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#extending_the_runtime) and this Github account has the actual docker files if the first link doesn't work (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docker)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I created a docker file image using `gcloud beta app gen-config` as suggested and then tagged it using `docker tag` and pushed it to the registry using `gcloud docker -- push` as per (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling). I discovered that at `gcloud app deploy` app engine creates images and uploads them to the image registry anyway so this was redundant. When I installed my image onto a VM instance, it didn't have any of the wordpress-helper.php files so unfortunately it isn't useful as development environment.

Comment: If you want to have a development environment on a GCE instance, can you just follow the steps on the GCE instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the docker image for the deployed app with the following command (replace VERSION and SERVICE).

```
gcloud docker -- pull $(gcloud --format='value(deployment.container.image)' app versions describe VERSION --service SERVICE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little dusty, but you can try the App Engine Flex emulator I put together :)

https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/flem